# Connect spark 3.4.0 (cluster master) and hadoop 3.3.5 (cluster) from spring boot 2.7.9

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark

I have one master node and two worker nodes. all nodes are running same version spark 3.4.0. Installed Hadoop 3.3.5 cluster on same. Spring boot dependencies are.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Java code is.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName("gbh")
        .setMaster(sparkUrl)
        .set("fs.defaultFS",hdfsUrl)

SparkSession sparkSession =     SparkSession.builder().master(sparkUrl).config(sparkConf).getOrCreate();
SparkContext sparkContext = sparkSession.sparkContext();
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.defaultFS", hdfsUrl);
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("HADOOP_USER_NAME", username);
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration());
Dataset<Row> resul = sparkSession.read().option("header", true).option("delimiter", ",").csv("hdfs:///user/root/address.csv");
resul.createOrReplaceTempView("Address");
Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Address");
dataset.foreach(row -> {
logger.info("row data =  "+row.toString());
});
```

I have tested in spark shell using pyspark --master spark://165.300.90.17:7077 its working same code with Scala. but in java i am getting below error

`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RpcEndpointVerifier$CheckExistence; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 5378738997755484868, local class serialVersionUID = 7789290765573734431`

Can you please guide me to resolve this issue. Thanks.

And also How can use Spark Connect for java.

Comment: the issue is maven dependency. i have changed spark-core_2.13 to spark-core_2.12 it's working fine. but getting another error `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: host.docker.internal`

Comment: 1) You should add provided Maven scope to Spark dependencies 2) If your code isn't running in a container, that's an expected error

Comment: Thanks. but the issue is resolved.just added `spark.driver.host` and `spark.driver.bindAddress` in SparkSession.

Comment: and one more thing don't use row.toString(). it will cause run time.

Comment: You should use dataset.show() rather than a foreach loop